# Android Things video playback on Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, video, raspberry-pi, android-things

Has anyone been able to successfully play a video using Android Things on a Raspberry Pi? If so was there anything special you had to do to get it to work? If not does any one know why it isn't working?

I made a simple video player that plays a local video from disk. The app runs fine on a phone but I get an error dialog on the Pi saying "Can't play this video".

One Thing I have already ran into but I think I solved was there are no content providers in Android Things, so instead of using a uri for the video source I gave it a file directly like so.

EDIT: Code edit

```
VideoView videoPanel;
.
.
.
videoPanel.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File("/sdcard/Movies/videoFile.mp4")));
```

Comment: Where is the file, specifically?

Comment: Oh sorry the video.src is a string and it is `/sdcard/Movies/videofile.mp4`

Comment: Do you hold the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission? Did you reboot your Thing after installing your app (as runtime permissions are not granted until after a reboot, due to current limitations in the preview)?

Comment: Yes I just double checked in debug mode and the permission is granted, and I rebooted as a sanity check.

Comment: can you also paste the output of `adb logcat`?

Answer (score 2):

I was using 0.5.1-devpreview with raspberry pi 3, and tried to use exoplayer to play mp4. Audio works but not video (just black screen). Same result for youtube iframe sdk (black screen with only audio playing).

Comment: The bug is tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67738615

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work for my project using `setVideoPath` instead of `SetVideoURI`. So your code would be

```
File file = new Java.IO.File("/sdcard/Movies/videoFile.mp4");
videoPanel.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: What Android Things version did you get this to work on? I saw there was an update recently but haven't updated it yet.

Comment: The latest developer preview, version 0.2

Comment: The video playback is kind of jumpy since they haven't added any support for OpenGL yet, but it does play at least.

Comment: FileNotFound(Permission Denied)  permission readExternalPermission is set

Comment: @Jason did you set the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest?

Comment: of course set, and reboot it, but i do not know the AT whether or not support the 1920*1080.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

to your activity in the manifest.